# Magento2: how to get customer collection using search functionality?

Tags: magento2, frontend, search, pagination

how to get customer collection using search functionality?

[image]

Comment: This seems like a front controller build which is sending param of input to controller and based on ajax response populating data. Can you confirm if that is the case, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used Magento default pagination functionality.

Comment: In the screenshot you are already getting data what else is needed? Do you mean you want the same functionality as in screenshot via search bar in header?

Comment: I want to search for data by email id.

Comment: Isn't that already being done in screenshot ,or do you mean you want more data, if that is the case please share the controller code, along with what data you want to get.

Comment: It is the only screenshot. I did not get data by email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85082/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-law).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/html/my-custom-form.phtml

```
<form action="<?= $block->getUrl("modulename/form/email"); ?>"
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="input-text" id="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
    <button type="submit" class="action" id="submit"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ok')) ?></span></button>
</form>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Controller/Form/Email.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Form;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
            $this->_coreRegistry->register('email', $email);
            return $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        }
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Email.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Email extends Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('email');
    }

    public function getCustomerCollectionByEmail()
    {
        return $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                    ->addAttributeToFilter("email", $this->getEmail())
                    ->load();
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/html/my-custom-form.phtml

```
<?php 

    $customerCollectionByEmail= $block->getCustomerCollectionByEmail(); 
    foreach ($customerCollectionByEmail as $customer) {
        echo $customer->getEmail();
    }
?>
```

I don't tested it but it should work !

Comment: Hi, It is working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck !