# How to add a frontend search box functionality for a custom table grid magento2

Tags: magento2, module, custom

I have created a custom module and get data in the list format, now I want to add search functionality on the list view, so how can I add that?

Comment: does that list is visible on the bacnend/frontend?

Comment: list is visible in fronend through custom module.@MrZid

Answer (score 0):

To make fulltext search work in magento 2 admin listing/grid you need to:

1. Add index to the table you use for storing your listing/grid data

```
$connection->addIndex(
                    'testtable', //table name
                    'title',    // index name
                    [
                        'title'   // filed or column name 
                    ],
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT //type of index
                );
```

2. Add **addFilter** method to you grid/listing DataProvider that calls it's collections **addFieldToFilter** or **addAttributeToFilter** method
3. In ui_component/listing.xml you need add node **filterSearch** between listingToolbar

   `<filterSearch name="fulltext"/>`

Comment: i want search functionality in fronend

Comment: In that case do refer this link. Might help you   https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/248452/85429